# Breakpoint Error w/ Firebase getting data from database

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, swift3

I changed code to match Swift 3 & xCode 8, but now I am getting breakpoint errors with this; I don't understand why

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        //when someone adds something new to database tell us here
        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).child("snaps").observe(FIRDataEventType.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in
            print(snapshot)

            let snap = Snap()

            let snapshotDictionnary = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

            //This will get the data from the list of emails
            snap.from = (snapshotDictionnary!["from"] as? String)!
            snap.imageURL = (snapshotDictionnary!["imageURL"] as? String)!
            snap.descript = (snapshotDictionnary!["description"] as? String)!


            self.snaps.append(snap)
            self.tableView.reloadData()


        })


    }
```

the breakpoint is coming from

```
let snapshotDictionnary = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
```

I didn't realize the issue was in regards to the blue arrows on the side. If anyone else is having this issue just click on a blue arrow and drag it off the screen.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: And why `NSDictionary`? This is Swift 3. Use a Swift dictionary.

Comment: There is no error it just crashes; it gives me a breakpoint error, the only thing that prints out is "(lldb) " and then it highlights "let snapshotDictionnary = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary" and says thread 1: breakpoint; im new to swift and ios im doing a course for it

Comment: Do you have a breakpoint set on that line (is there a blue pointed rectangle on the line number)?

Comment: ahh i fixed it now; what exactly does that blue pointed rectangle mean??

Comment: It's a breakpoint. It tells the debugger to stop your app on that line so you can do some debugging. Now would be a good time to find some tutorials on using the Xcode debugger. It will make your app development far less painful.